# Multiple intents in other languages than English

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-assistant

Using Watson with workspace in Portuguese Brazil I'm always receiving the response.intents array with max one item. Only one intent.

So I can't handle for example pizza + business hours in the same request.

Is there any limitation for multiple intents in other languages than English?

---

Just Portuguese Examples to test:

Pizza intent: "Gostaria de pedir uma pizza"

Business hours intent: "Qual horario você fecha?"

Pizza and Address request: "Gostaria de pedir uma pizza, mas horario você fecha?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application code you need to set `alternate_intents = true`.

See MessageRequest section in the documentation.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/curl.html?curl#get-a-response-to-a-user-39-s-input-there-is-no-rate-limit-for-this-operation

If you want to show all intents in the "try it out" section, add `<? intents ?>` to a node that will run.

---

Just to add on what you are trying to achieve. By default Watson Assistant will handle only one intent, that being the top one (and if only confidence > 0.2).

To handle two intents, you first need to know if there is really two intents. To do this, you can use k-means to see if this is the case.

There is sample code and more details here:

https://sodoherty.ai/2017/02/06/compound-questions/